# Javascript OnclickOff

Tags: javascript

I have a div that I want to trigger a function when I click on it (easy enough using onclick) that shows child divs that have been hidden. I also want to make it so that when you click anywhere else on the document after the child divs have been shown, it will hide the child divs.

I am not sure of the best way to approach this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(this).click(handleGeneralClick);
});

function handleGeneralClick(evt)
{
    if ($(evt.currentTarget).attr('id') == 'my_div')
    {
        // Show child div's
    }
    else
    {
        // Hide child divs
    }
}
```

Or something like that anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Put an onclick handler on the body element. This handler will contain the code to hide the div.

Comment: right but if you click on the div, it toggles the body as well.

Comment: You can put a click handler in the div that does nothing except "event.cancelBubble=true;" then the body handler is never invoked.